# Refatoração de código PHP para fornecer imagem com tamanho especifico

Tags: php, imagem, refatoração, compressão-de-imagem

O código em baixo visa fornecer uma imagem com medidas especificas para minimizar o seu tamanho e assim optimizar o carregamento do web-site.

## Problema

A imagem demora mais de 1 segundo a ser fornecida, tornando-se um peso considerável no carregamento inicial do web-site:

[image: Captura de Tela - Análise do GET]

O tamanho recolhido são 76,5KB mas o tempo de espera pelo servidor é assustador estando entre 800ms e 900ms:

[image: Captura de Tela - Divisão em ms do GET]

**Imagem original**
Se puxar a imagem original, a mesma demora cerca de 430ms para 160,7KB.

## Código PHP

O código em baixo recebe a largura e altura da tela.
Prepara a imagem para as medidas recebidas e devolve a mesma para o navegador:

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");

$file = "bg_body.jpg";

if (is_file($file)) {    
    $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    $source_imagex = $dest_imagex = imagesx($source_image);
    $source_imagey = $dest_imagey = imagesy($source_image);

    if (isset($_GET["w"]) && ctype_digit($_GET["w"])) {
        $dest_imagex = $_GET["w"];
    }

    if (isset($_GET["h"]) && ctype_digit($_GET["h"])) {
        $dest_imagey = $_GET["h"];
    }

    $dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_imagex, $dest_imagey);
    imagecopyresampled($dest_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $dest_imagex, $dest_imagey, $source_imagex, $source_imagey);
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    imagejpeg($dest_image,NULL,70);

} else {
    echo "Image file not found!";
}

ob_end_flush();
```

## Pergunta

Como posso optimizar este código com o objectivo final de reduzir o tempo que o mesmo demora a gerar a imagem para enviar ao navegador?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Embora possa haver alguma otimização específica que possa ser feito no algoritmo de redimensionamento de imagem, acredito que a saída correta para o seu problema é fazer cache de imagens com tamanhos diferentes no momento do *upload* e não no momento da visualização ou *download* da imagem.

Estive lendo sobre o modo [como o Facebook disponibiliza bilhões de fotos](https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=76191543919). Basicamente eles armazenam a imagem em 4 tamanhos diferentes e procuram garantir que a leitura seja feita rapidamente.

Sobre o seu caso, uma possibilidade é criar algumas variações de tamanho e então enviar a que mais se aproxime do tamanho requisitado pelo usuário, sendo o redimensionamento final, um ajuste fino, feito via `width` e `height` no HTML ou CSS.

Outra técnica seria armazenar as imagens redimensionadas após gerá-las e, caso já existam, ler diretamente o arquivo. Isso vai deixar o primeiro acesso mais lento, já que além de redimensionar a imagem será necessária escrevê-la no disco, porém isso é bom se se a quantidade de visualizações for grande, já que apenas o primeiro acesso será impactado e os demais serão servidos sem processamento adicional.

Neste segundo cenário, ainda é possível usar faixas de valores para não incorrer em gerar imagens de tamanhos semelhantes. Por exemplo, a imagem com 1000 pontos de largura é usada se o usuário solicitar imagens na faixa de 801 a 1000, enquanto a versão de 800 pixels é usada se a solicitação for de 601 a 600 pixels.

Enfim, as duas propostas consistem em criar caches das imagens (1) no momento do envio ou (2) na primeira requisição.

Obviamente, as duas tem efeitos diferentes no desempenho e no armazenamento necessário. Criar imagens por demanda atrasa o primeiro acesso mas economiza disco.

Comment: Eu acho que no momento do envio é mais apropriado. O usuário já espera que upload de qualquer coisa seja demorado, independente da velocidade de sua conexão. Mas ele perceber demora ao visualizar a imagem pode acabar tendo a impressão errada quanto a estabilidade do site ou servidor.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Concordo que geralmente é melhor. Só em casos muito específicos não acho necessário. Por exemplo, se é um sistema de intranet ou para uso restrito por um grupo de usuários, pois então eles estarão mais preocupados com a funcionalidade do que com esses detalhes e ninguém vai fazer questão de pagar por um super HD.

Comment: Acho que a solução vai mesmo passar por alterar o _backend_ e deixar imagens com intervalos de tamanhos para evitar este problema. +1 Pela sugestão e comparação com um dos "_cavalões_" :) Vou esperar no entanto a ver se alguém aponta alguma falha no código que possa estar por trás da demora... continuo a achar que mais de 1 segundo para redimensionar uma imagem é muito tempo!

Comment: @Zuul Faz algum tempo que não trabalho com manipulação de imagens em PHP, mas pelo que lembro e também por uma breve pesquisa que fiz, não parece haver algo nesse código para ser otimizado. O problema da demora pode estar na prioridade do processo, na capacidade do processador ou na falta de aceleração por *hardware* (placa de vídeo *offboard*).